# Заменить &lt; на символы UTF

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно в строке заменить текст типа `&lt;`, `&laquo;` на сами символы?

Comment: [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: "hello &lt; world".replace("&lt;", "<символ>")

Comment: @Grundy спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно конвертировать только *специальные* HTML-сущности (такие, как: `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&#039;`, `&lt;` и `&gt;`)? то можно воспользоваться функцией [*htmlspecialchars_decode()*](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

Если же необходимо преобразовать *все* сущности подходящие типу документа и кодировке, то используйте функцию [*html_entity_decode()*](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php) :

```php
<?php
$str = "заменить текст типа &lt;, &laquo; на сами символы";
echo html_entity_decode($str); // заменить текст типа <, « на сами символы
?>
```